# Excel Cells always null

Tags: c#, excel

So here's my code to read excel worksheet

```
Application ExcelApp;
Workbook Workbook;
ExcelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
Workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(file);
var worksheet = (Worksheet)Workbook.Sheets[1];
```

When i'm trying to use name instead of index when choosing sheets i'm exception.
But now every Cell in this worksheet returns null

```
((Range)worksheet.Cells)["A1"]
```

or

```
((Range)worksheet.Range["A2","A3"]).Cells
```

It always return null and i don't know why

Comment: I guess your worksheet should be Sheet[0].

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Bad index when i try Sheets[0].
I have 3 sheets in this file

Comment: Isn't minimun index 1? I mean, shouldn't it be `Sheets[1]` the first worksheet, `Sheets[2]` the second one, and so on?